# Mathematical underpinnings of variations on Silverman's bandwidth

Tags: kernel-smoothing

When using a Gaussian kernel to estimate the distribution of a Gaussian-distributed $x$, the bandwidth that minimizes the mean integrated squared error is:

$$h=\left(\frac{4 \hat{\sigma}^5}{3n}\right)^{\frac{1}{5}} $$

where $\hat{\sigma}$ is the estimated standard deviation of $x$ and $n$ is the sample size. I have seen the derivation of this result.

I am aware there are adjustments that use the inter-quartile range rather than $\hat{\sigma}$ and also that use $0.90$ rather than $1.06=\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{5}}$. I am aware that these adjustments are motivated by the fact that $x$ may not be normally distributed and may be skewed.

I have not seen mathematical justification for these adjustments or an explanation of why the adjustments are "optimal". The adjustments feel arbitrary to me. Is there mathematical justification of these?